# RVest sometimes works, sometimes returns 0 nodes

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am relatively new to web scraping, and I have recently been using rvest.

I am scraping news headlines, paragraphs, and links from a Yahoo News page (about 10 of each at a time). The code I am using to do it is below:

```
headlines <- read_html(url) %>%
    html_nodes("#web a") %>% 
    html_text() 

paragraphs <- read_html(url) %>%
    html_nodes("#web p") %>% 
    html_text()

links <- read_html(url) %>%
    html_nodes("#web a") %>% 
    html_attr("href")
```

My issue is that sometimes my code works perfectly and I get what I need (three vectors of info, each of length 10), and then a second later on another test it returns nothing:

```
> headlines <- read_html(url) %>%
+     html_nodes("#web a") %>% 
+     html_text()
> headlines
character(0)
```

Does anyone know why this is or how to make this more reliable? I am putting the code into a dashboard and want to be able to reliably check the top news articles every day. Does rvest/Yahoo News maybe have rate limits that are blocking me? I am currently unaware of any. For context too - I am testing the dashboard constantly (100 times a day minimum), is it possible that this could be overworking it?

Thank you in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't store `read_html(url)` and then run your individual `html_nodes` off of that stored variable? If the website does anything dynamic (rotates stories, varies them, randomly chooses, etc), then the order or even presence of some stories would differ. As to why it sometimes returns 0, sorry, don't know that one.

Comment: Good question. There isn't a reason why I did it that way. I actually just adjusted per your suggestion. Unfortunately this does not resolve the issue (although it is a good thing to do anyway so thanks for the suggestion).

Comment: Have you checked the response status in case blocked ?